# How do I toggle the contents of a FAQ on clicking each of them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, performance

```js
const faqItems = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-question");
const faqContents = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-content");

for (item of faqItems) {
    console.log(item);

    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for(content of faqContents){
            console.log(content)
        };
    })   
}
```

```css
.faq {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 90px;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
    color: white;
}

.faq-title {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.faq-list {
    width: 65%;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.faq-item {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faq-question {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #303030;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faq-question svg {
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faq-question svg path {
    fill: white;
}

.faq-content {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #303030;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    display: none;
}

.member h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

.member .email-2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.email-2 input {
    width: 68%;
}
```

```html
<section class="faq">
            <h1 class="faq-title"> Frequently Asked Questions </h1>

            <ul class="faq-list">
                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        What is Netflix?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Netflix is a streaming service that offers a wide variety of award-winning TV shows, movies, anime, documentaries, and more on thousands of internet-connected devices. <br>
                            You can watch as much as you want, whenever you want without a single commercial – all for one low monthly price. There's always something new to discover and new TV shows and movies are added every week!
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        How much does Netflix cost ?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Watch Netflix on your smartphone, tablet, Smart TV, laptop, or streaming device, all for one fixed monthly fee. Plans range from ₦1,200 to ₦4,400 a month. No extra costs, no contracts.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        Where can I watch?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Watch anywhere, anytime. Sign in with your Netflix account to watch instantly on the web at netflix.com from your personal computer or on any internet-connected device that offers the Netflix app, including smart TVs, smartphones, tablets, streaming media players and game consoles. <br>
                            You can also download your favorite shows with the iOS, Android, or Windows 10 app. Use downloads to watch while you're on the go and without an internet connection. Take Netflix with you anywhere.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        How do I cancel?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Netflix is flexible. There are no pesky contracts and no commitments. You can easily cancel your account online in two clicks. There are no cancellation fees – start or stop your account anytime.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        What can I watch on Netflix?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Netflix has an extensive library of feature films, documentaries, TV shows, anime, award-winning Netflix originals, and more. Watch as much as you want, anytime you want.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        Is Netflix good for kids?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            The Netflix Kids experience is included in your membership to give parents control while kids enjoy family-friendly TV shows and movies in their own space. <br>
                            Kids profiles come with PIN-protected parental controls that let you restrict the maturity rating of content kids can watch and block specific titles you don’t want kids to see.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="member">
                <h2>Ready to watch? Enter your email to create or restart your membership.</h2>

                <div class="email-2">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
    
                    <button class="get-started">
                        Get Started
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I want to display the hidden contents of a FAQ when I click on each one of the buttons. My code displays every contents if I click on just one. How do I fix this ??

```js
const faqItems = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-question");
const faqContents = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-content");

for (item of faqItems) {
    console.log(item);

    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for(content of faqContents){
            console.log(content)
        };
    })   
}
```

```css
:root {
    --red: #e50914;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.front-page {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(/assets/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
}


.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,transparent 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.7)),radial-gradient(50% 100%,transparent 0,rgba(0,0,0,.7) 100%);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.front-page .header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 45px;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px;
}

svg {
    width: 140px;
    z-index: 2;
}

svg path {
    fill: var(--red);
}

.sign-in {
    background-color: var(--red);
    border: none;
    padding: 7px 17px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 75px 0;
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 950px;
}

.title {
    max-width: 640px;
    font-size: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.sub-title {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 200;
    max-width: 640px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.email-text {
    font-size: 22px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.email {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: -60px;
}

input {
    padding: 25px;
    width: 35%;
    z-index: 2;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.get-started {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: var(--red);
    z-index: 2;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.two {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
}

.sub-two {
    color: white;
    width: 40%;
}

.sub-two h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.sub-two p {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.img-two img {
    max-width: 85%;
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.three {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 90px;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
}

.sub-three {
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
}

.sub-three h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.sub-three p {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.img-three img {
    max-width: 85%;
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.four {
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
}

.text {
    width: 45%;
}

.four h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.four p {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.five {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 90px;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
}

.sub-five {
    color: white;
    width: 55%;
}

.sub-five h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.sub-five p {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.img-five img {
    max-width: 85%;
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.faq {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 90px;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
    color: white;
}

.faq-title {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.faq-list {
    width: 65%;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.faq-item {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faq-question {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #303030;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faq-question svg {
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faq-question svg path {
    fill: white;
}

.faq-content {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #303030;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    display: none;
}

.member h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

.member .email-2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.email-2 input {
    width: 68%;
}

.footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 200px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #737373;
    gap: 20px;
}

.col-1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.col-2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.col-2 p {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.col-1:hover, .col-2 p:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.col-3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
    <title>Netflix Nigeria - Watch TV Shows Online, Watch Movies Online</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="front-page">
            <div class="header">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 111 30" class="svg-icon svg-icon-netflix-logo" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><g id="netflix-logo"><path d="M105.06233,14.2806261 L110.999156,30 C109.249227,29.7497422 107.500234,29.4366857 105.718437,29.1554972 L102.374168,20.4686475 L98.9371075,28.4375293 C97.2499766,28.1563408 95.5928391,28.061674 93.9057081,27.8432843 L99.9372012,14.0931671 L94.4680851,-5.68434189e-14 L99.5313525,-5.68434189e-14 L102.593495,7.87421502 L105.874965,-5.68434189e-14 L110.999156,-5.68434189e-14 L105.06233,14.2806261 Z M90.4686475,-5.68434189e-14 L85.8749649,-5.68434189e-14 L85.8749649,27.2499766 C87.3746368,27.3437061 88.9371075,27.4055675 90.4686475,27.5930265 L90.4686475,-5.68434189e-14 Z M81.9055207,26.93692 C77.7186241,26.6557316 73.5307901,26.4064111 69.250164,26.3117443 L69.250164,-5.68434189e-14 L73.9366389,-5.68434189e-14 L73.9366389,21.8745899 C76.6248008,21.9373887 79.3120255,22.1557784 81.9055207,22.2804387 L81.9055207,26.93692 Z M64.2496954,10.6561065 L64.2496954,15.3435186 L57.8442216,15.3435186 L57.8442216,25.9996251 L53.2186709,25.9996251 L53.2186709,-5.68434189e-14 L66.3436123,-5.68434189e-14 L66.3436123,4.68741213 L57.8442216,4.68741213 L57.8442216,10.6561065 L64.2496954,10.6561065 Z M45.3435186,4.68741213 L45.3435186,26.2498828 C43.7810479,26.2498828 42.1876465,26.2498828 40.6561065,26.3117443 L40.6561065,4.68741213 L35.8121661,4.68741213 L35.8121661,-5.68434189e-14 L50.2183897,-5.68434189e-14 L50.2183897,4.68741213 L45.3435186,4.68741213 Z M30.749836,15.5928391 C28.687787,15.5928391 26.2498828,15.5928391 24.4999531,15.6875059 L24.4999531,22.6562939 C27.2499766,22.4678976 30,22.2495079 32.7809542,22.1557784 L32.7809542,26.6557316 L19.812541,27.6876933 L19.812541,-5.68434189e-14 L32.7809542,-5.68434189e-14 L32.7809542,4.68741213 L24.4999531,4.68741213 L24.4999531,10.9991564 C26.3126816,10.9991564 29.0936358,10.9054269 30.749836,10.9054269 L30.749836,15.5928391 Z M4.78114163,12.9684132 L4.78114163,29.3429562 C3.09401069,29.5313525 1.59340144,29.7497422 0,30 L0,-5.68434189e-14 L4.4690224,-5.68434189e-14 L10.562377,17.0315868 L10.562377,-5.68434189e-14 L15.2497891,-5.68434189e-14 L15.2497891,28.061674 C13.5935889,28.3437998 11.906458,28.4375293 10.1246602,28.6868498 L4.78114163,12.9684132 Z" id="Fill-14"></path></g></svg>
                <button class="sign-in">Sign In</button>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <h1 class="title">Unlimited movies, TV shows, and more.</h1>
                <h2 class="sub-title">Watch anywhere. Cancel anytime.</h2>
                <p class="email-text">Ready to watch? Enter your email to create or restart your membership.</p>   
            </div>

            <div class="email">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">

                <button class="get-started">
                    Get Started
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>

        <section class="two">
            <div class="sub-two">
                <h1>Enjoy on your TV.</h1>
                <p>Watch on Smart TVs, Playstation, Xbox, Chromecast, Apple TV, Blu-ray players, and more.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="img-two">
                <img src="/assets/tv.png" alt="tv">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="three">
            <div class="img-three">
                <img src="/assets/mobile-0819.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="sub-three">
                <h1>Download your shows to watch offline.</h1>
                <p>Save your favorites easily and always have something to watch.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="four">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Watch everywhere.</h1>
                <p>Stream unlimited movies and TV shows on your phone, tablet, laptop, and TV.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="five">
            <div class="img-five">
                <img src="/assets/kids.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="sub-five">
                <h1>Create profiles for kids.</h1>
                <p>Send kids on adventures with their favorite characters in a space made just for them—free with your membership.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="faq">
            <h1 class="faq-title"> Frequently Asked Questions </h1>

            <ul class="faq-list">
                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        What is Netflix?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Netflix is a streaming service that offers a wide variety of award-winning TV shows, movies, anime, documentaries, and more on thousands of internet-connected devices. <br>
                            You can watch as much as you want, whenever you want without a single commercial – all for one low monthly price. There's always something new to discover and new TV shows and movies are added every week!
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        How much does Netflix cost ?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Watch Netflix on your smartphone, tablet, Smart TV, laptop, or streaming device, all for one fixed monthly fee. Plans range from ₦1,200 to ₦4,400 a month. No extra costs, no contracts.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        Where can I watch?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Watch anywhere, anytime. Sign in with your Netflix account to watch instantly on the web at netflix.com from your personal computer or on any internet-connected device that offers the Netflix app, including smart TVs, smartphones, tablets, streaming media players and game consoles. <br>
                            You can also download your favorite shows with the iOS, Android, or Windows 10 app. Use downloads to watch while you're on the go and without an internet connection. Take Netflix with you anywhere.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        How do I cancel?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Netflix is flexible. There are no pesky contracts and no commitments. You can easily cancel your account online in two clicks. There are no cancellation fees – start or stop your account anytime.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        What can I watch on Netflix?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            Netflix has an extensive library of feature films, documentaries, TV shows, anime, award-winning Netflix originals, and more. Watch as much as you want, anytime you want.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="faq-item">
                    <button class="faq-question">
                        Is Netflix good for kids?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="faq-content">
                        <article>
                            The Netflix Kids experience is included in your membership to give parents control while kids enjoy family-friendly TV shows and movies in their own space. <br>
                            Kids profiles come with PIN-protected parental controls that let you restrict the maturity rating of content kids can watch and block specific titles you don’t want kids to see.
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="member">
                <h2>Ready to watch? Enter your email to create or restart your membership.</h2>

                <div class="email-2">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
    
                    <button class="get-started">
                        Get Started
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


        <section class="footer">
            <div class="col-1">Questions? Contact Us.</div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="row-1">
                    <p>FAQ</p>
                    <p>Invstor Relations</p>
                    <p>Privacy</p>
                    <p>Speed Test</p>
                </div>

                <div class="row-2">
                    <p>Help Center</p>
                    <p>Jobs</p>
                    <p>Cookie Prefrences</p>
                    <p>Legal Notices</p>
                </div>

                <div class="row-3">
                    <p>Account</p>
                    <p>Ways to Watch</p>
                    <p>Corporate Information</p>
                    <p>Only on Netflix</p>
                </div>

                <div class="row-4">
                    <p>Media Center</p>
                    <p>Terms of Use</p>
                    <p>COntact Us</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">Netflix Nigeria.</div>
        </section>
        
    </main>

    <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the FAQ section. How can I be able to click on each one of the faqs and display the contents specific to each one of them ?? When I click on just one of the buttons every one of the contents display. How can I be able to fix this ?

Comment: @lupz I have done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually assigning CSS styles via javascript, alternating `display: block` and `display: none`

```js
const faqItems = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-question");
const faqContents = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-content");

for (item of faqItems) {
  
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // CLOSE ALL FAQS
    for (let i=0; i<faqContents.length; i++) {
      faqContents[i].style.display = 'none'
    }

    // OPEN THE CLICKED FAQ
    e.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = 'block'
  })
  
}
```

```css
.faq {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 90px;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
  color: white;
}

.faq-title {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.faq-list {
  width: 65%;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.faq-item {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faq-question {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.faq-question svg {
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.faq-question svg path {
  fill: white;
}

.faq-content {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.member h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

.member .email-2 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.email-2 input {
  width: 68%;
}
```

```html
<section class="faq">
  <h1 class="faq-title"> Frequently Asked Questions </h1>

  <ul class="faq-list">
    <li class="faq-item">
      <button class="faq-question">
                        What is Netflix?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
      <div class="faq-content">
        <article>
          Netflix is a streaming service that offers a wide variety of award-winning TV shows, movies, anime, documentaries, and more on thousands of internet-connected devices. <br> You can watch as much as you want, whenever you want without a single
          commercial – all for one low monthly price. There's always something new to discover and new TV shows and movies are added every week!
        </article>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="faq-item">
      <button class="faq-question">
                        How much does Netflix cost ?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
      <div class="faq-content">
        <article>
          Watch Netflix on your smartphone, tablet, Smart TV, laptop, or streaming device, all for one fixed monthly fee. Plans range from ₦1,200 to ₦4,400 a month. No extra costs, no contracts.
        </article>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="faq-item">
      <button class="faq-question">
                        Where can I watch?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
      <div class="faq-content">
        <article>
          Watch anywhere, anytime. Sign in with your Netflix account to watch instantly on the web at netflix.com from your personal computer or on any internet-connected device that offers the Netflix app, including smart TVs, smartphones, tablets, streaming media
          players and game consoles. <br> You can also download your favorite shows with the iOS, Android, or Windows 10 app. Use downloads to watch while you're on the go and without an internet connection. Take Netflix with you anywhere.
        </article>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="faq-item">
      <button class="faq-question">
                        How do I cancel?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
      <div class="faq-content">
        <article>
          Netflix is flexible. There are no pesky contracts and no commitments. You can easily cancel your account online in two clicks. There are no cancellation fees – start or stop your account anytime.
        </article>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="faq-item">
      <button class="faq-question">
                        What can I watch on Netflix?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
      <div class="faq-content">
        <article>
          Netflix has an extensive library of feature films, documentaries, TV shows, anime, award-winning Netflix originals, and more. Watch as much as you want, anytime you want.
        </article>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="faq-item">
      <button class="faq-question">
                        Is Netflix good for kids?
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M23.25 37V24.75H11v-1.5h12.25V11h1.5v12.25H37v1.5H24.75V37Z"/></svg>
                    </button>
      <div class="faq-content">
        <article>
          The Netflix Kids experience is included in your membership to give parents control while kids enjoy family-friendly TV shows and movies in their own space. <br> Kids profiles come with PIN-protected parental controls that let you restrict the
          maturity rating of content kids can watch and block specific titles you don’t want kids to see.
        </article>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="member">
    <h2>Ready to watch? Enter your email to create or restart your membership.</h2>

    <div class="email-2">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">

      <button class="get-started">
                        Get Started
                    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: How can I click a second time to hide the contents and also change the icon when it's open ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to rewrite your code and use the summary and details attribute (see example below)

```html
<details>Netflix is a movie streaming service
     <summary>Netflix</summary>
</details>
```